# Using a subquery vs. a variable as a filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, subquery

Creating my lengthy query I had to filter for a machine number which is stored in another table. To avoid having to join another (read: 9th) table to the query, I opted in to convert the code of the machine to the machine Id by using a subquery:

> Join astComponents CAT ON Concat(CAT.Code, '_', CAT.Specification) =
>   AT.Code and CAT.AssetId = **(Select top 1 Id from astAssets where Code =
>   '2018090125')**

Total query execution time: 00:01:25

I then decided to make a variable out of this filter to see what the effect would be on the execution time. The variable being declared before the `select` statement, and used in the `join` statement:

> Declare @Mach int
>
> Set @Mach = (Select top 1 Id from astAssets Where
>   Code = '2018090125')

-

> Join astComponents CAT ON Concat(CAT.Code, '_', CAT.Specification) =
>   AT.Code and CAT.AssetId =  **@Mach**

Total query execution time: 00:00:15

Can someone explain me this major difference in execution time? The subquery to extract the machine code is very rapid, but I am thinking having the subquery as the filter opposed to a variable causes it to be executed each line.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you post the execution plans :) 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ I'd expect your variable method to be almost as fast as hard-coding the value.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, I'm heavily restricted by the database administrators.

Comment: Well, can they then? Why can't you? It isn't sensitive... kind of hard to troubleshoot performance without it. Darn near impossible

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because query plans are needed to troubleshoot this performance difference and these aren't able to be provided.

Comment: Ask the admins. The compatibility level is also set ridiculously low, I can't even split a string.

Comment: You can't create a udf to split a string? I mean, you can do that on 2005... and I can't ask your admins, I don't know them. You could though :)

Comment: Let me rephrase: I can split strings, but in a devious way, because I can't use the STRING_SPLIT function native to SQL server.

Comment: query execution plan is in fact information that could be used by a miscreant, due to the 'security in depth' principle, there would be an argument not to disclose it in public.

Comment: if your compatibility level is low, then performance lifts in later versions of SQL may not be getting used.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery in your larger query appears to be *uncorrelated*:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM astAssets WHERE Code = '2018090125')
```

That is, SQL Server can evaluate this subquery completely independently of the rest of your query.  If so, then the penalty for having it there is just the penalty of running the subquery once.

That your attempt to cache the result of the subquery speeds things up a bit is to be expected, but I don't expect the subquery to be a major factor in the overall performance of the larger query.

Side note: SQL Server is smart enough to recognize that the subquery does not change row to row.  So, it will likely execute it once, and cache the result somewhere.

Comment: "...but I don't expect the subquery to be a major factor in the overall performance of the larger query"
You may expect not so, but to confirm I have just reran both queries. They're exactly identical aside from what I have already shown. Runtimes: 00:01:33.459 vs. 00:00:29.000

Comment: Your numbers may be somewhat arbitrary.  You need to check the query plans of both, and see how much estimated/actual time is being spent in evaluating the standalone subquery.  Otherwise, what you posted above is just apples to oranges.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, I'm heavily restricted by the database administrators. Can you explain why they're arbitrary? Execution times appear to be rather consistent.

Comment: Well, the numbers you posted don't prove anything AFAIK.  What you are suggesting doing is not typical SQL development style, at least not what I have seen.

Comment: I don't understand how they don't prove anything, when I am consistently getting such execution times. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you really wanted to continue down that path, you would need to scale things up.  Your numbers imply that storing the subquery result in a temp variable speeds up the query by a factor of 3.  But, how many records are in your table?  If you scale up to say 1 million records, is there still a factor of 3 difference?  Do you understand what I am trying to tell you?

Comment: Yes, I see now. Unfortunate that I can't share the plans. Would have been interesting to find out the reason for this!

Comment: In general, I wouldn't worry about _non_ correlated subqueries.  Most of the time, they will just show up as constant, one-time, penalties in your execution plan.  _Correlated_ subqueries, on the other hand can be real performance killers.  If you have a lot of those, then it might be time to rethink how you are phrasing your query.

Comment: It's the only subquery in my query, fortunately. There's already plenty of Joins and functions that slow down the query.

Comment: do you always get this performance difference?  Data could have become chached after the first test that you ran.

Comment: Difference stays, although execution times are less long after the first time